# Excel split cost figure between months with partial dates

Tags: excel, date

I have a list of cost figures with start dates and end dates which I need to split between months, I have searched for the solution to this problem but cannot seem to find one that will work with partial months i.e.( startdate:01/01/2015 enddate: 15/04/2015 cost:10000) which would leave figures like Jan:2857, Feb:2857, Mar:2857, Apr:1429.

I have been trying to modify this example: http://www.excel-university.com/excel-formula-to-allocate-an-amount-into-monthly-columns/ but having no luck getting the partial months working.

Any suggestions or help would be most welcome. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

if you calculate it on daily basis, would it be ok? the result would be:

```
01.01.2015  01.02.2015  01.03.2015  15.04.2015
 2.857,14    2.857,14    2.857,14    1.428,57
```

your `daily amount` is:

```
=10.000/(DAYS360(startdate;enddate;TRUE)+1)
```

(be carefull of `true` and `false` argument)

under the dates or instead of `2.857,14` etc. insert the formula:

```
=IF(DAY("your date")>1;DAY("your date");30) * daily amount
```

This formula assumes that you want to have 30 days in each month:

```
=IF(DAY(01.01.2015)>1;DAY(01.01.2015);30)
```

result = `30`

```
=IF(DAY(15.04.2015)>1;DAY(15.04.2015);30)
```

result = `15`

so if months begins with a date different from the `1st` it will give you the number of days.

if you want to match months with your `startdate` and `enddate` (if i understood your comment correctly), you could do:

```
=IF(OR(
       AND(MONTH(startdate)=MONTH(your date);YEAR(startdate)=YEAR(your date));
       AND(MONTH(enddate)=MONTH(your date);YEAR(enddate)=YEAR(your date))
      );"match";"no match")
```

by this you make sure that month and year correspond.

If you want to get the number of days in a month automatically, you could use:

```
=DAY(DATE(YEAR("your date");MONTH("your date")+1;1)-1)
```

but this does not assume anymore 30 days, you can change it with `if statement`

I hope this helps,

Best - AB

Comment: Hi there,

This seems to work but I must then change the 30 for each month correct? so in the example it would be changed to 15 for April?

I am looking to do that bit automatically, would there be a way to match the months in the date and if they match minus or subtract the full month based on whether its the start or end date?

Also could you explain what the L997 is please?

Comment: If i did not get your question, please ask

Comment: I managed to get it working using the following formula
`=IF(AND($C4-DAY($C4)+1<=E$2,$D4>=E$2),$B4*((1+MIN($D4,DATE(YEAR(E$2),MONTH(E$2)+1,0))-MAX($C4,E$2))/(1+$D4-$C4)), " ")`

Where C= startdate E=monthstart D=enddate and b=value